# Лямбда выражение захват по значению

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string captive{ "test string" };

    auto lambda{ [captive](std::string string) -> void
    {
        std::cout << "capture: " << captive << std::endl;
        std::cout << "parameter: " << string << std::endl;
    } };

    captive = "not test string";

    lambda(std::move(captive));

    return 0;
}
```

Out:

```
capture: test string
parameter: not test string
```

В момент создания лямбда-выражения происходит захват по значению, соотв. создаётся копия строки, которая должна быть доступна в момент вызова лямбда-выражения.

Вопрос: каково время жизни этой захваченной переменной? (буду благодарен, если будет ссылка на стандарт)

Comment: Время жизни будет как у поля объекта `lambda`

Comment: Захваченная по значению переменная остается сама по себе, а само захваченное значение становится частью лямбды. Так что время жизни копии - такое же, как и время жизни самой лямбды...

Comment: Лямбда - это класс с перегруженным `()`. В классе создается поле с типом `std::string`, и в него копируется захваченная переменная.